# Caveats in 4e Lite

Tags: dnd-4e, house-rules

I'm planning to use the [4e Lite](http://ponderingsongames.com/2012/03/25/4elite/) houserule set for my next game. If anyone here has used it, are there any hidden problems you've encountered while playing?

More specifically, I want to know if it doesn't throw out too many things (considering the amounts of stuff churned out for the system by the sourcebooks and the Dragon magazine) besides magic items, and if there are some character building parts I might want to look out for with the players - like particular accuracy/defence boosting powers that gain too much weight in 4e Lite.

Comment: You should try to narrow your question a bit. Is there something that makes you think there will be problems with this system? Are you anxious about a specific thing you really want this system to fulfill?

Comment: @AnneAunyme Thank you, I'll try to narrow it down.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.se! Unfortunately, “Does *X* system have problems?” is a really broad question — too broad for a workable Stack question. We can certainly help if you do run into specific problems with it, but for a more wide-ranging question about what people think about a given game, the Stack format fails. For that specific purpose, you might want to leverage the discussion-based strengths of [an RPG discussion forum](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449). Sorry again, and cheers!

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Thank you for the clarification. I'll try to be more precise in the future, but I suppose this one cannot be salvaged.

Comment: No problem, and no harm. Certain questions work better than others in the peculiar system the site has, and some questions not at all. It's hyper-specialised for solving directly-experienced problems rather than anticipated or hypothetical ones, or “any warnings” kinds of questions. Thanks for participating, and good luck starting a discussion about this! We hope to see you when you run into a conundrum that's more concrete — the site excels at those.